# GROUP BY number with aggregate being a date

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

In a table I have an account number and a corresponding date. From a query I want to get only distinct account numbers and a corresponding date. Can I do this in 1 query or does there need to be multiple queries? If I use: SELECT DISTINCT account, date; then a still get duplicate accounts since it looks for unique combinations of account and date. If I use GROUP BY then how do I select only 1 date if there are multiple dates to 1 account?

Comment: Which of the dates do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an account number and a date? And the account number can be redundant, if there are more than one dates? Then you get a logical problem, because which date should sql select?

```
account number | date
---------------------------------------
1002 | 2013-01-01
1003 | 2013-03-12
1003 | 2013-03-13
1003 | 2013-03-16
1004 | 2013-06-11
```

You can use functions like "max" or "min". If you need a more complex logic, let us know:

```
Select account, max(date) FROM tablename GROUP BY account
```

So you will get unique account numbers with the latest date.